# PHP DB connection and password verification

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have three errors

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in
>   /Volumes/shared/Digital/_Websites/_TEST/qpm/classes/mysql.php on line
>   20
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /Volumes/shared/Digital/_Websites/_TEST/qpm/classes/mysql.php on line
>   23
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /Volumes/shared/Digital/_Websites/_TEST/qpm/classes/mysql.php on line
>   23

Here is my code

```
<?php 
require_once 'includes/constants.php';
class mysql{
    private $conn;

    function __construct(){
        $this->conn = $conn = new MySQLi(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
            or die ('There was an error in the connection');
        }

    function verify ($un, $pwd){


            $username = $un;
            $password = $pwd;
            if ($sth = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT pass FROM User WHERE username = '".$un."' LIMIT 1")) {
            $sth->execute();

            $user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            // Hashing the password with its hash as the salt returns the same hash
            if (crypt($password, $user->hash) == $user->hash) {
              return true;
            } else { 

                return false; }

            }//end of if;

        }//end of verify

    }//enfd of class
```

Just trying to get pass and return true if its the same or false if not

Thanks

Comment: `$this->conn = $conn =` why is that..?

Answer (score 0):

Like many, many, many other php users, you are confusing 2 totally different APIs - mysqli and PDO.

Please, choose one, namely [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info), and make your code consistent with it.

Here goes the code with all the useless stuff taken out,
yet with proper things, namely **prepared statements**, added:

```
function verify ($un, $pwd)
{
    $sql = "SELECT pass FROM User WHERE username = ?"
    $sth = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array($un));
    $pass = $sth->fetchColumn();
    return (crypt($pwd, $pass) == $pass);
}
```

**but note that this function of `verify` should not be a method of `mysql` class**